# Casting away lifetime constraints?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write a Rust function that casts an input from one lifetime constraint to a same-typed output with a global lifetime constraint (conceptually something like `unsafe fn foo<'a, T1, T2>(x: T1) -> T2 where T1: 'a, T2 = T1 + 'static`), but I can't quite figure out how to write it without adding indirection layers like `Box`. Any ideas?

More generally, I'm trying to implement an unsafe `thread::scoped` in terms of `mem::transmute` and `thread::spawn`. `spawn` requires `'static` bounds on its `T` and `F` parameters, but `scoped` does/should not.

Comment: `unsafe fn foo<'a, T>(x: T + 'a) -> T + 'static` doesn’t make sense—it’s not syntactically valid. What are you *actually* writing?

Comment: It should take an input of some type with some lifetime constraint, and return an output of the same type with a global lifetime constraint. I've tried to clarify the post, but if I knew the correct syntax for the signature, I wouldn't have a problem - I could just `mem::transmute`.

Comment: Are you talking about things like `Box<Any + 'static>`? Those only make sense for trait objects. Or do you mean bounds such as `fn no_borrows<T: 'static>(x: T) -> T { x }`?

Comment: More like the latter. I want to cast from a version of T with one lifetime to a version of T with a greater lifetime. (unsafely, of course).

Comment: @bfops: what you are describing now is simply not possible. A type satisfies a certain lifetime requirement, which is known statically. There can be no transmutation or such things between them. For the concept of your `T2` to exist, `T1` must be `'static` already. What you seem to be trying to implement is flatly impossible and always will be.

Comment: So it is impossible to implement `scoped` in terms of `spawn`, even using arbitrary amounts of `unsafe`? That seems strange. I feel like `unsafe` exists for the purpose of circumventing rusty constraints..

Comment: It is possible to implement `scoped` using unsafe code. However, it is not possible to implement it in terms of `spawn`. You can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c1b8bd2d6fd4a00522635112d3f7b28501552a65/src/libstd/thread/mod.rs#L303) to see how this is done un the unstable `thread::spawn`.

Comment: I mean, copy-pasting the code is obviously doable. But it seems kind of strange that it's not possible to even unsafely implement `scoped` in terms of spawn. The mechanics are basically the same, no? `unsafe` has generally been there for me when I wanted to use an abstraction potentially unsafely, and take on the responsibility of correctness myself. Implementing scoped this way doesn't seem fundamentally incorrect.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17):

Although I had a similar problem, **I do not recommend extending lifetime constraints**. It's almost certain that a different approach is in order for situations where this comes up.

That said, you can extend a lifetime in the latest Rust stable (1.29.0 as of this writing) via [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/std/mem/fn.transmute.html#examples).

Example from the docs (with the caveat "**This is advanced, very unsafe Rust!**"):

```
struct R<'a>(&'a i32);
unsafe fn extend_lifetime<'b>(r: R<'b>) -> R<'static> {
    std::mem::transmute::<R<'b>, R<'static>>(r)
}
```

Comment: The answer is a few years old now is it still the best way?

Comment: @JosephGarvin I haven't fully kept up with all the latest developments, but I don't know of any other way to do this. The latest 1.51.0 docs still provide this example: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.51.0/std/mem/fn.transmute.html

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing now is simply not possible. A type satisfies a certain lifetime requirement, which is known statically. There can be no transmutation or such things between them. For the concept of your `T2` to exist, `T1` must be `'static` already. What you seem to be trying to implement is flatly impossible and always will be.

It is possible to implement `scoped` using unsafe code, but it is not possible to implement it in terms of `thread::spawn`. You can take a look at the [source code of `thread::scoped` in Rust 1.3.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.3.0/src/libstd/thread/mod.rs#L276-L284) to see how this was done. Be aware that `thread::scoped` was removed because it had [soundness issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292), so it isn't a perfect example to copy wholesale.